# we can have two instances 'failed' on queue at laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

i need implement mongodb and have a question;
at queue.php we have

```
'failed' => [
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

but I need to put MongoDB too at the same time, would have problems if duplicate 'failed' position?

Exist another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should only use one database to store your failed jobs.

If you use [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) you can use MongoDB to store your failed jobs. [Here](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#queues) is the documentation for that.

This would be a sample configuration for using MongoDB to save failed jobs:

```
'failed' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    // You can also specify your jobs specific database created on config/database.php
    'database' => 'mongodb-job',
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```